# Loops in didSet

Tags: swift, foreach, for-in-loop, didset

We came across this odd behaviour when using loops in a didSet. The idea was that we have a data type with a tree structure and in each element we wanted to store the level that item is on. So in the didSet of the `level` attribute we would also set the level attribute of the children. However we realised that this does only work if one uses `forEach` and not when using `for .. in`. Here a short example:

```
class Item {

    var subItems: [Item] = []
    var depthA: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            for item in subItems {
                item.depthA = depthA + 1
            }
        }
    }
    var depthB: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            subItems.forEach({ $0.depthB = depthB + 1 })
        }
    }

   init(depth: Int) {
        self.depthA = 0

        if depth > 0 {
            for _ in 0 ..< 2 {
                subItems.append(Item(depth: depth - 1))
            }
        }
   }

   func printDepths() {
        print("\(depthA) - \(depthB)")

        subItems.forEach({ $0.printDepths() })
   }
}

let item = Item(depth: 3)
item.depthA = 0
item.depthB = 0
item.printDepths()
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
0 - 0
1 - 1
0 - 2
0 - 3
0 - 3
0 - 2
0 - 3
0 - 3
1 - 1
0 - 2
0 - 3
0 - 3
0 - 2
0 - 3
0 - 3
```

It seems like it will not call the didSet of the subItems attribute when it's called from an `for .. in` loop. Does anyone know why this is the case?

UPDATE:
The problem is not that the didSet is not called from the init. We change the attribute afterwards (see last 4 lines of code) and only one of the two depth attribute will propagate the new value to the children

Comment: [property observers are not invoked during init in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Comment: I'd say this behavior is complex enough to warrant a function. For one, it dispels any doubts about whether or not it's called in the `init`.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-419. Using a closure (and as others have noted, `defer`) escapes the (currently broken) semantic analysis that prevents the calling of a `didSet` observer from within itself; `for item in subItems { { item.depthA = depthA + 1 }() }` also works.

Comment: And [this will now be fixed in Swift 5 mode](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/15280) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use defer, for updating any optional properties or further updating non-optional properties that you've already initialized and after you've called any super init methods, then your willSet, didSet, etc. will be called.

```
        for item in subItems {
            defer{
                item.depthA = depthA + 1
            }
        }
```

When you use the **forEach** it makes kindOf "contract" with the elements and because it's an instance method unlike **for .. in** loop, it triggers the **didSet** of the variable. The above case applies where we use the loop, we have to trigger the **didSet** manually

This Solves the problem I think. Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks! But why do I need this in a `for .. in` loop and in a `forEach` it is not necessary?

Comment: @M.Schrick When you use the forEach it makes kindOf "contract" with the elements and because it's an instance method unlike for .. in loop, it triggers the didSet of the variable. The above case applies to the case where we use the loop we have to trigger the didSet manually. I Hope it makes sense?

Comment: Do you have by any chance a link at hand where I can read up on that?

Comment: @M.Schrick Since it's a higher order function(forEach) for more information you can research on the closure that it takes as an argument.I think getting to the basics of how all these higher order functions work made it clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the `init`, didSet is not called.

Tried this line on the Swift REPL

```
class A { var a: Int { didSet { print("A") } }; init() { a = 5 } }
```

Then called `A()`

didSet is NOT called

But

```
A().a = 7
```

Found that didSet is called

So, the solution is to make a function (prefered to be `final`), that makes your effect you need to put in `didSet`. Then call it both from `didSet` and from `init`. You can put this in your class.

```
final func updateA() {
    // Do your "didSet" here
}

var a: Int {
    didSet {
        updateA()
    }
}

init() {
    a = 5
    updateA()
}
```

So in your case:

```
func updateDepthA() {
    for item in subItems {
        item.depthA = depthA + 1
    }
}

var depthA: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        updateDepthA()
    }
}

...

init(depth: Int) {
    self.depthA = 0
    updateDepthA()

    ...
```

Comment: The problem is not that the didSet is not called from the init. We set the `depth` attribute after the initialisation (see the last four lines of code) and the didSet of the child attributes will not be called if we use a `for .. in` loop.